# EXECUTE FORMAT() USING in postgres is showing error for $

Tags: stored-procedures, plpgsql

i will directly get to the code rather than explaining too much

```
execute format('
                "$1" = select "Source1" from temp_tables._%s;
                '::text, (translate("Song_Id_"::text, '-', '_')))
using "Source1__";
```

the table is dynamically created and the table name is all fine as i have used that table to insert some data into it. if i run this code, the error i am getting is

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: $1 = select "Source1" from temp_tables._24af1593_3539_49fd_9...
        ^
QUERY:  $1 = select "Source1" from temp_tables._24af1593_3539_49fd_9ef4_29307f301d38;
```

i have tried other method too like

```
execute
        '$1 = select "Source1" from temp_tables._' || (translate("Song_Id_"::text, '-', '_')) ||';'
        using "Source1__";
```

even this gives the same error.

**note : "Source1__" is a variable of type text declared in the stored procedure where everything else is being executed too.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong. The `EXECUTE` command accepts only SQL statements. There is nothing statement like `var = SELECT ...`. More - the you can pass just value by using clause `USING`. You cannot to pass any reference to variable. Solution is easy. Just use clause `INTO`

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT ... ' INTO target_plpgsql_variable
```

Please, read [related documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). Unfortunately, some parts the stored procedures are not extra intuitive because there is mix of two very different languages. It is good by reading documentation, because is hard to find correct solution without knowledge of possibilities and syntax.